# PL SQL Values of a variable need to be cleared or reset to default

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I've a variable as follows,

`T_ID_LIGNE TBL_ID_LIGNE;`

Later I'm loading some data into this variable, performing operations with the data in it.
Now I need to clear the data in it and load fresh data. I don't want to use any extra variable.

Is is possible?

Please help

Thanks.

Comment: what is the type `TBL_ID_LIGNE`?

Comment: @Dmitry Its custom type, anyways I will give it.

Type TBL_ID_LIGNE   is table of T_ERRALIM_EA4.ERR_N_LINEID%Type index by binary_integer;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T_ID_LIGNE.DELETE will delete all collection

```
EXISTS(n) - Returns TRUE if the specified element exists.
COUNT - Returns the number of elements in the collection.
LIMIT - Returns the maximum number of elements for a VARRAY, or NULL for nested tables.
FIRST - Returns the index of the first element in the collection.
LAST - Returns the index of the last element in the collection.
PRIOR(n) - Returns the index of the element prior to the specified element.
NEXT(n) - Returns the index of the next element after the specified element.
EXTEND - Appends a single null element to the collection.
EXTEND(n) - Appends n null elements to the collection.
EXTEND(n1,n2) - Appends n1 copies of the n2th element to the collection.
TRIM - Removes a single element from the end of the collection.
TRIM(n) - Removes n elements from the end of the collection.
DELETE - Removes all elements from the collection.
DELETE(n) - Removes element n from the collection.
DELETE(n1,n2) - Removes all elements from n1 to n2 from the collection.
```

Comment: Thanks, Lemme try it @user2879235